# Will sp_recompile flag objects from other Databases for recompile? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In the technet article for sp_recompile below the remarks section states

"**sp_recompile looks for an object in the current database only.**"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238892(v=sql.80).aspx

Is this referring to the parameter for the function of the objects that it can mark for recompile?

For example if I have a table in database A that is used by an object in database B, Will the object in Database B get marked for recompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note only procedural objects will be recompiled. Triggers and Stored procedures, not entire tables also be aware triggers and SP are merely flagged to recompile, the recompilation will occur only next time they are called.

Second it will recompile only objects in the actual database it mean if you are in context of DataBase_A and tries to recompile DataBase_B.dob.SP_InAnotherDatabase it will not work.

Also it does not states will be "nested" recompiles. So if you recompile objectA and it uses a objectB (in same or another DB, does not matter) that objectB will be not recompiled.

Comment: Great thanks. This is a problem as I will need to manually recompile things on database b in this case. It answers some of the problems that have happened recently on our Databases.